# How to list all the people who have worked with 'Art Garfunkel'?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables `actor`, `movie`, `casting`. I have to find the people who have worked with actor "ART Garfunkel".

I have solution but I am not able to understand how the following query works.

```
**movie**   **actor**    **casting**
   id          id           movieid
   title       name         actorid
   yr                       ord
   director     
   budget       
   gross        

SELECT a.name
  FROM (SELECT movie.*
          FROM movie
          JOIN casting
            ON casting.movieid = movie.id
          JOIN actor
            ON actor.id = casting.actorid
         WHERE actor.name = 'Art Garfunkel') AS m
  JOIN (SELECT actor.*, casting.movieid
          FROM actor
          JOIN casting
            ON casting.actorid = actor.id
         WHERE actor.name != 'Art Garfunkel') as a
    ON m.id = a.movieid;
```

one more solution:

```
  SELECT actor.name  FROM casting
       JOIN movie ON movie.id=casting.movieid
      JOIN actor ON  actor.id=casting.actorid
     WHERE actor.name !='Art Garfunkel'
    AND
       movie.id IN(SELECT movie.id FROM casting
           JOIN movie ON movie.id=casting.movieid
       JOIN actor ON  actor.id=casting.actorid
        WHERE actor.name='Art Garfunkel')
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy Solution:

```
SELECT distinct actor.name
FROM movie
JOIN casting
ON casting.movieid = movie.id
JOIN actor
ON actor.id = casting.actorid
where movie.id in (select movieid from casting join actor on id =actorid where 
actor.name = 'Art Garfunkel') and actor.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplified version that does the same thing:

```
select actor.name
from (
    select movieid from casting
    join actor on actor.id = casting.actorid 
        and actor.name = 'Art Garfunkel'
) ag_movies
join casting on ag_movies.movieid = casting.movieid
join actor on actor.id = casting.actorid 
    and actor.name != 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Yours follows roughly the same steps:

1. Get the movieid for all movies Art Garfunkel was in.
2. Find the cast lists for all those movies.
3. Get the artist names from the cast lists that are not Art Garfunkel.

The casting table is a cross-lookup table which allows many actors to act in many movies. Through the casting table we have to find all the movies Art was in and then reverse that to find the other actors in those movies.

The joins mean the result will only contain rows from both tables which match the join criteria. So `on actor.id = casting.actorid and actor.name = 'Art Garfunkel'` connects the tables by the matching IDs but limits the results to only those IDs where the actor name is Art's. The join as used in these queries means the same as intersection from set theory.

The sub-select inside the parenthesis creates a temporary table (named ag_movies in this example) that can be used by the parent query just like any other table.

Comment: It works, but there's a typo: movidid should be movieid

Comment: What is ag_movies?  Is that some form of variable?  What is the rule for creating one?

Comment: "ag_movies" is an ALIAS for the sub-query. Might have been clearer if that line was ") AS ag_movies". The AS is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for MySQL:

```
SELECT name FROM actor JOIN casting ON actor.id = actorid JOIN movie ON movie.id = movieid WHERE movie.id IN (
SELECT movieid FROM casting 
WHERE actorid IN (SELECT id FROM actor WHERE name  = 'Art Garfunkel') 
) AND actor.name != 'Art Garfunkel';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question... here is my suggested solution:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Actor A
INNER JOIN
    Casting C
ON
    C.ActorID = A.ID
WHERE C.MovieID IN (
    SELECT
        C.MovieID
    FROM
        Casting C
    INNER JOIN
        Actor A
    ON
        C.ActorID = A.ID
    WHERE
        Actor = 'Art Garfunkel'
)
WHERE
        Actor <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

The sub-query first finds all movies that the actor is in. The second outer query finds all actors that have acted in a movie that is returned from said sub query.

Comment: am getting the below error for ur query.
Error:
Table 'gisq.Actor' doesn't exist

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? You are likely in the wrong context. Try `USE [Your_Database_Name] GO` at the start of the query.

Comment: Actually am using SQl  ZOO webstie to (practice )                                                                 

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM actor
JOIN casting ON actor.id = actorid WHERE casting.movieid IN 
(SELECT movieid FROM casting WHERE name != 'Art Garfunkel' AND
actorid in (SELECT actor.id FROM actor WHERE name =  'Art Garfunkel'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM actor 
JOIN casting ON id=casting.actorid 
WHERE movieid IN(
    SELECT movieid FROM casting 
    WHERE actorid IN(
        SELECT id FROM actor 
        WHERE name = 'Art Garfunkel')) 
AND name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.NAME
FROM   casting c
       JOIN actor a
         ON c.actorid = a.id
WHERE  c.movieid IN (SELECT c.movieid
                     FROM   casting c
                            JOIN actor a
                              ON c.actorid = a.id
                     WHERE  a.NAME = 'Art Garfunkel')
       AND a.NAME <> 'Art Garfunkel'
ORDER  BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will solve the issue:

```sql
select distinct name 
  from actor  
  join casting on id=actorid
 where actorid IN
              (select actorid
                 from casting 
                where movieid IN
                      (select movieid 
                         from casting 
                        where actorid = 
                                     (select id from actor where 
                                       name= 'Art Garfunkel')
                       )
               )
and
name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name

FROM actor
    JOIN casting ON (actorid=id)

WHERE movieid IN (SELECT movieid

                  FROM casting
                     JOIN actor ON (actorid=id)

                  WHERE name='Art Garfunkel')
     AND name<>'Art Garfunkel'
```

The queries posted in question are quite convoluted. A simple query will help you understand the logic flow better. Starting from subquery we select the list of 'movieid' starring 'Art Garfunkel'. The main query selects all the actors in the list of movies returned by subquery. In the final step we have to remove the entries of 'Art Garfunkel' himself else his name will also come in the list. 'Art Garfunkel' could not have worked with 'Art Garfunkel' himself.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT name FROM actor 
    JOIN casting on actor.id= actorid
    
     WHERE casting.movieid IN
          (SELECT movie.id FROM movie
          JOIN casting ON movie.id = movieid
          JOIN actor ON actor.id = actorid
          WHERE actor.name = 'Art Garfunkel') AND name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

I find translating my code in root level easier to understand before unravelling. So it goes like this:-
Get names of actors WHERE Art Garfunkel stars in  AND name IS NOT Art Garfunkel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM actor 
WHERE id IN(SELECT c.actorid 
            FROM casting c
            JOIN actor a ON c.actorid = a.id
            WHERE c.movieid IN(
                  SELECT c.movieid
                  FROM casting c
                  JOIN actor a
                  ON a.id = c.actorid
                  WHERE a.name = 'Art Garfunkel')) AND NOT name = 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name from actor a join casting c on a.id=c.actorid where c.movieid in 

(select c.movieid from casting c join actor a on c.actorid=a.id where a.name='Art Garfunkel') and a.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from actor a join
casting c on c.actorid=a.id
where movieid in (select movieid from casting 
where actorid in (select id from actor
where name ='Art Garfunkel'))
and name <> 'Art Garfunkel';
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest solution i have got so far for this question:

```
select actor.name from actor 
/* fetch all the actor names from actor_ids (fetched below) */
where id in 
    (select casting.actorid from casting where movieid in 
     /* fetch all the actor_ids from movie_ids (fetched below) */
         (select movieid from casting join actor on actor.id=casting.actorid
          where actor.name='Art Garfunkel'))
         /* fetch all the movie_ids in which 'Art Garfunkel' has worked */
and actor.name <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution without any heavy join operation is for those who aim for better performamce

```
select name from actor where id in (select actorid from casting where movieid in (select movieid from casting where actorid in (select id from actor where name = 'Art Garfunkel'))) and name != 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select name from casting 
join movie on movieid=id
join actor on actorid=actor.id
where movieid in (select movieid from casting
join actor on actorid=id
where name='Art Garfunkel')
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your solution by executing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.NAME
FROM   actor a
       JOIN casting c
         ON a.id = c. actorid
WHERE  movieid IN(SELECT movieid
                  FROM   casting
                         JOIN actor
                           ON actor.id = casting.actorid
                  WHERE  NAME = 'Art Garfunkel')
       AND NAME <> 'Art Garfunkel'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from casting join actor on (actorid=actor.id) 
where 
movieid IN
(select movieid from casting join actor on (actorid=actor.id)join movie on(movieid=movie.id) where name=  'Art Garfunkel')
and name!= 'Art Garfunkel'
```